# Crucial M4 256 SSD is showing bad sectors

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I have an HP DM3 1048 laptop (yes, a 2010 classic)
From the very beginning I’ve been using Windows 2008 server R2 on in.
About 3 years ago I installed a SSD (Crucial M4 256 GB)
I installed Ubuntu 14.04 as well (on dual boot), my system became an arrow and I was nearer to the perfect laptop efficiency!

However about 2 months ago I got some weird behavior.

- sudden Linux reboots
- Frequent Windows “InpageError”

So I got back in the fear of the HDD era, physical damage!

Since we have actually chips rather than platters, I’ve been reading the entire concept behind the SSD vs HDD differences. Enough to desperate a little more.

I run some `scandisk` on Windows and what happened after cleaning th Windows with `scandisk`? Windows effectively cleaned disk errors, but the problems appeared again. so some applications still crashed.

Since I trust more the Linux diagnostics / tools, however I got stuck trying to “clean” the disks: No success.

Ubuntu works fine most of times, a little slower maybe.

What should I do?

How can I make an in-depth search and repair, so that I can resume working or otherwise evidence that the SSD is damaged beyond repair? Is this the time to get a new SSD drive?

EVIDENCE / screenshots:

The status showing in Ubuntu:

[image: SSD Ubuntu smart data]

[image: SSD partitioning]

[image: Ubuntu warning - file system is not clean]

**Windows**

[image: status showing in Windows with the manufacturers diagnosis tool]

*"storage executive"*

[image: status showing in Windows with the SSDlifepro tool]

[image: windows error - InPageError]

Comment: Can you please add the missing image links? You could insert some spaces in them to bypass the two links limit caused by your still low reputation score, I'll edit and fix them then, just leave me a comment "@ByteCommander".

Comment: @ByteCommander thanks for giving me a hand!, i have put the link part to bypass the restriction.